# Workflow to send alerts every 2 hours in the period of work

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, alert

I created three lists,

- department working period List, containing (department name, start work, and the end of the work),
- Employee List, containing fields (employee's name, postal address, section belongs to it)
- alerts List, containing fields (the name of the task, assign to, has executed (Yes No field)

**My question is**: How can I do workflow for the list, number 3, send an alert message every two hours for employees, during the period of work, until it is modified field, (has executed), to yes?

I could not stimulation only every two hours during the work period

I hope to benefit from the developers, thanks for your support

Comment: Can any one help me to do that ?

Comment: Which SharePoint version is this?

Comment: sharepoint 2013

Answer (score 0):

You could use a SharePoint 2013 workflow to that has logic similar to this:

**Stage 1**

- Pause for 2 hours
- If [Has Executed] equals Yes

  - Stop Workflow and Log Message
- Else

  - Send Email to user

**Stage Transition**

Go to Stage 1

Comment: how can i send email for employees only during working period ( between start time work and end time work ) ?

Comment: What does your Start/End columns look like? Whats some sample data?

Comment: i can keep the start and end work from employee list with condition of email = assign to field